# If I use "In all honesty", I would be considered as dishonest before?

Tags: meaning

cambridge gives this about "in all honesty"

> said when expressing your opinion honestly, seriously, or truthfully

a comment in this link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TizxLEYhhQM&t=7s in comments box, not in the video) says

> "In all honesty" or "honestly" implies that you're usually dishonest.

Is that true? If I use "In all honesty", I would be considered as dishonest before?

Comment: Don’t believe what you read in comments

Comment: No. It could mean that you are giving an honest answer rather than saying what you think the other person wants to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People can be dishonest when they are being polite.  This is sometimes called "tact" or "white lies".

> Purple hair!... I think it really suits you.

Saying "in all honesty" suggests that the speaker is choosing not to be tactful. It doesn't mean that the speaker normally lies, it might mean that the speaker usually tries to be polite.

> In all honesty, I think purple hair was a mistake. You look like clown.

Comment: So, what the speaker would say might be a little bit hurt, right?